# Matplotlib axes only with values on Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, charts

I'm working on a backlog chart since last year, and now with the new year,and now I'm facing this issue:

[image: Bugged Chart]

I had to multiply the number of the year to keep the X axis keep rolling to the right.
But after that, I got this blanked interval on X axis from 202052 (concatenate year + week of the year number) until 202099~ .

My indexes doesn't have these values. As below :

```
(Int64Index([202026, 202027, 202028, 202029, 202030, 202031, 202032, 202033,
             202035, 202036, 202037, 202038, 202040, 202041, 202043, 202044,
             202045, 202046, 202047, 202048, 202049, 202050, 202051, 202052,
             202101, 202102],
            dtype='int64'),
 Int64Index([202026, 202027, 202028, 202029, 202030, 202031, 202032, 202033,
             202034, 202035, 202036, 202037, 202038, 202040, 202041, 202043,
             202044, 202045, 202046, 202047, 202048, 202049, 202050, 202051,
             202052, 202101, 202102],
            dtype='int64'),
 Int64Index([202026, 202027, 202028, 202029, 202030, 202031, 202032, 202033,
             202034, 202035, 202036, 202037, 202038, 202040, 202041, 202043,
             202044, 202045, 202046, 202047, 202048, 202049, 202050, 202051,
             202052, 202101, 202102],
            dtype='int64'))
```

How can I drop these values?

Thank you!

EDIT: Adding full code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from matplotlib.lines import Line2D
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import matplotlib.cbook as cbook
from matplotlib.ticker import MaxNLocator

%matplotlib inline

df = pd.read_csv(
    "/home/eklon/Downloads/Venturus/NetSuite/Acompanhamento/130121/MelhoriasNetSuite130121.csv", delimiter=';')


df.columns = df.columns.str.replace(' ', '')    

df['CreatedDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['CreatedDate'])
df['CompletedDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['CompletedDate'])
df['DayCompleted'] = df['CompletedDate'].dt.dayofweek
df['DayCreated'] = df['CreatedDate'].dt.dayofweek
df['WeekCreated'] = df['CreatedDate'].dt.isocalendar().week
df['WeekCompleted'] = df['CompletedDate'].dt.isocalendar().week
df['YearCreated'] = df['CreatedDate'].dt.year
df['YearCompleted'] = df['CompletedDate'].dt.year
df['firstCompletedDate'] = df.CompletedDate - df.DayCompleted * timedelta(days=1)
df['firstCreatedDate'] = df.CreatedDate - df.DayCreated * timedelta(days=1)

df['YearWeekCreated'] = df['YearCreated']*100 + df['WeekCreated']
df['YearWeekCompleted'] = df['YearCompleted']*100 + df['WeekCompleted']


df_done = df[df['Progress'] == 'Completed']
df_open = df[df['Progress'] != 'Completed']
df_todo = df[df['BucketName'] == 'To do']
df_doing = df[df['BucketName'] == 'Doing']
df_consult = df[df['BucketName'] == 'Em andamento RSM']
df_open['Priority'].value_counts().sort_index()
df['Priority'].sort_index()

df_backlog_created = df['YearWeekCreated'].value_counts().sort_index()
df_backlog_completed = df['YearWeekCompleted'].value_counts().sort_index()
df_backlog = df_backlog_created.cumsum() - df_backlog_completed.cumsum()




#============================================================================


qtd_created = df['YearWeekCreated'].value_counts().sort_index()
idx_created = qtd_created.index
qtd_completed = df['YearWeekCompleted'].value_counts().sort_index()
idx_completed = qtd_completed.index 
qtd_backlog = df_backlog
idx_backlog = qtd_backlog.index

idx_completed = idx_completed.astype(int)


fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(14,10))



#plt.figure(figsize=(14,10))
ax.plot(idx_created, list(qtd_created), label="Iniciadas", color="r")
ax.plot(idx_completed, list(qtd_completed), label="Completadas", color="y", linewidth=3)
ax.bar(idx_backlog, qtd_backlog, label="Backlog", color="b")
ax.legend(['Novas', 'Fechadas', 'Backlog'])



x=[1,2,3]
y=[9,8,7]


for a,b in zip(idx_created, qtd_created): 
    plt.text(a, b, str(b), fontsize=12, color='w', bbox=dict(facecolor='red', alpha=0.5), horizontalalignment='center')




for a,b in zip(idx_backlog, qtd_backlog): 
    plt.text(a, b, str(b), fontsize=12, color='w', bbox=dict(facecolor='blue', alpha=0.5), horizontalalignment='center')



for a,b in zip(idx_completed, qtd_completed): 
    plt.text(a, b, str(b), fontsize=12, color='black', bbox=dict(facecolor='yellow', alpha=0.5))


plt.title('Backlog', fontsize= 20)
```

Comment: could you post your code for a detailed look?

Comment: Otherwise, you need to create a dummy index columns as the order of each x-tick labels. Kr.

Comment: please take a look at solution. You will need to take the method but not the code direct. hope this helps. kr.

Answer (score 1):

This is not direct fix for your code, but the principle should be the same.
I will create a fake dataframe and illustrate the problem and a solution.

Current empty space problem:

```
labels = [202026, 202027, 202028, 202029, 202030, 202031, 202032, 202033,
             202034, 202035, 202036, 202037, 202038, 202040, 202041, 202043,
             202044, 202045, 202046, 202047, 202048, 202049, 202050, 202051,
             202052, 202101, 202102]
y = np.random.rand(len(labels))

# old approach, will have empty space
_, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)
ax.plot(labels, y)
```

[image: example plot with spaces]

Suggested solution:

```
labels = [202026, 202027, 202028, 202029, 202030, 202031, 202032, 202033,
             202034, 202035, 202036, 202037, 202038, 202040, 202041, 202043,
             202044, 202045, 202046, 202047, 202048, 202049, 202050, 202051,
             202052, 202101, 202102]
y = np.random.rand(len(labels))

# suggested by dummy index
x_idx = range(len(labels))
_, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)
ax.plot(x_idx, y)
ax.set_xticks(x_idx[::5])
ax.set_xticklabels(labels[::5])
```

[image: plot without empty space]

Hope this works work for you. Kr.

Comment: there are two major issues with your solution: 1) the tick label don't correspond to the data (the data go up to 202102 whereas you axis labels end short after 202032), 2) if you pan / zoom your axes you'll get weird x axis labels. So better not set fixed labels on an Autolocator.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is called index plotting (just pass the y values to `plot`, no x values), so you should use an [`IndexLocator`](https://matplotlib.org/api/ticker_api.html?highlight=autolocator#matplotlib.ticker.IndexLocator). In the following example you set a tick every 4th row:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as mt

np.random.seed(0)
idx = [202026, 202027, 202028, 202029, 202030, 202031, 202032, 202033,
             202035, 202036, 202037, 202038, 202040, 202041, 202043, 202044,
             202045, 202046, 202047, 202048, 202049, 202050, 202051, 202052,
             202101, 202102]
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(len(idx)), index=idx, columns=['col1'])

fig,ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(df.col1.to_numpy())
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mt.IndexLocator(4,0))
ax.xaxis.set_ticklabels(df.iloc[ax.get_xticks()].index)
```

[image]

Another possibility is to use a [`FuncFormatter`](https://matplotlib.org/api/ticker_api.html#matplotlib.ticker.FuncFormatter), especially if you want to zoom your chart as it will dynamically format the autolocator ticks:

```
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mt.FuncFormatter(lambda x,_: f'{df.index[int(x)]}' if x in range(len(df)) else ''))
```

[image]